# Convex functions in probability: $h(\alpha x_1 + (1 - \alpha)x_2) \le \alpha h(x_1) + (1 - \alpha)h(x_2)$

Tags: probability, inequality, convex-analysis

I was studying probability and came across this statement:

> If $h(x)$ is a convex function, that is, for $0 \le \alpha \le 1$
>
> $$h(\alpha x_1 + (1 - \alpha)x_2) \le \alpha h(x_1) + (1 - \alpha)h(x_2)$$
>
> for example $h(x) = x^2$ or $h(x) = e^x$, then for any $x_0$ there always exists a $b$ such that the line $h(x_0) + b(x - x_0)$ lies below $h(x)$, that is
>
> $$h(x) \ge h(x_0) + b(x - x_0)$$
>
> for any $x$. In particular, $h(X) \ge h(EX) + b(X - EX)$ for some $b$.

This entire thing looks like nonsense to me. The claims that it makes do not follow (are not implied by) the previous statements. For instance, it says that $h(\alpha x_1 + (1 - \alpha)x_2) \le \alpha h(x_1) + (1 - \alpha)h(x_2)$, but then it says that this implies that $h(x) \ge h(x_0) + b(x - x_0)$, which is at least unclear.

Could someone please clear this up, so that I can understand what point it's trying to make? Thank you.

Comment: @MartinR Paul Frost's answer starts discussing the definition of a convex function $f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) \le tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2)$ in the latter half of his answer, but I don't think it discusses $h(x) \ge h(x_0) + b(x - x_0)$ (and certainly not $h(X) \ge h(EX) + b(X - EX)$). It's not the definition of convex function that I'm having difficulty with, but rather the stuff that comes after. The statement is just so vague, that it's not clear how the stuff after the definition follows.

Comment: Paul demonstrates that “... for any $a \in [f'_-(x_0),f'_+(x_0)] $ and $x \ne x_0$ we get $a(x - x_0) \le f(x) - f(x_0)$.” Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: @MartinR Oh, sorry, you're right.